# get uid from url_alias in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

my url looks like this

```
http://localhost/incollect/spencer-gallery
```

i would like to obtain uid from this page to compare it with

```
$user->uid
```

Help what can i do I want to obtain uid from that node

Comment: Could you be more specific? Why and where do you need the user ID? In Views, in a custom module or theme? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
$acc = user_load(arg(1)); //This is based on the url path
if ($user->uid == $acc->uid){
  ...some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Lookup system URL by alias and turn the system url into string array
$path = drupal_lookup_path('source', request_path());
$pathArr = explode("/", $path);

//Load node object if the page is of a node
if($pathArr[0] === 'node' && isset($pathArr[1])) {
$node = node_load($pathArr[1]);
//You can get any properties from the loaded node now, uncomment the line below to see it
//drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($node, true) . "</pre>");
$nid = $node->nid;
$uid = $node->uid;
}
```

Comment: Please note that the uid above is of the node's author. To get uid of current user, use global $user.

Comment: Wow - that really is an inefficient method. Use: if(arg(0)=='node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) $nid = arg(1); to get the nid...

Comment: @FelixEve I'm aware of the method using arg(), but since I started using Drupal with Drupal 7, there is a note specific to this function, here is is the excerpt copied from the drupal.org 
....Avoid use of this function where possible, as resulting code is hard to read...When attempting to use this function to load an element from the current path... https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7

Comment: I think that is good advice on the Drupal page and passing named variables into functions is always preferable, however in this instance I think that using arg is acceptable and would also be more efficient.